# Automatically added -2 in permalink after set number as permalink

Tags: permalinks

My website's permalink structure is `/%postname%/` and I want to create permalink with number, for example for every new post I will create 1, 2, 3, etc. permalink for newer posts. But right now when I create permalink with 1, 2 or 3 then system automatically add `-2` after number, and it becomes `1-2`, `2-2`, `3-2`.

WordPress is installed in subdirectory on Nginx server and working fine.

What should I need to change?

**[Edit <sup>Feb 13 UTC</sup>] More Details**

- I started a forum and I didn't want to use a long permalink structure — by default, with the `/%postname%/` structure, WordPress uses title as permalink and if user posted a post (a forum topic) with long title, then there will be long permalink which I don't want.
- So I'd like to have a short permalink like `https://example.com/123` (i.e. `<site URL>/<number>`) and I think setting ID, or using the `/%post_id%/` structure, is good approach. But, how we can set it continuous (`1`, `2`, `3` etc. for newer post)? Right now when I published 3 posts, the permalink became `/1/`, `/3/`, `/8/`, and I don't know where is other ID number inserted because didn't add tag, cat or anything in between.

Comment: "*I don't know where is other id number inserted because didn't add tag, cat or anything in between*" - they're probably [revisions/autosaves](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/revisions/) or posts created programmatically by a plugin

Comment: Thank you for sharing, i will disable revisions. No it's fresh website and have not too much plugins, only installed cache plugin's.

Comment: Disabling revisions doesn't guarantee sequential post IDs (for posts in the same post type), so you might better off use a custom post type with a permalink structure like `forum/<id>` where `forum` is the rewrite base and `<id>` is a number (but not the post ID). As for the sequential number (forum ID), you can use a custom taxonomy or custom post meta, and automatically increment it when you *publish* your post.

Comment: Last answer is good. we have finally decided to continue with id's, it is the best option. Thank You for answering. :)

Comment: I have edited your post/question, so I suggest you to delete your 1st and 2nd comments, because I already deleted mine - but keep in mind that the `<site URL>/<number>` structure can conflict with date archives (e.g. a year archive at `example.com/2023`), hence WordPress added those suffixes (`-2` in question). As for that "last answer" in your previous comment, I assumed you set `/%post_id%/` as your permalink structure, and that you **disabled *revisions***; however, please write an answer so that we know for sure what you did to solve the issue in question. 

Comment: Thanks @sally-cj Yes, it's working fine after disable revisions in wp_config.php file.`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );` Sorry for late reply.